# Best way write Integration Test for Spring WebClient which invokes an external REST API over internet?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a Spring boot application which has a RESTFul API (RestController). As part of the logic, whenever there is a call to this endpoint, it calls a service class which invokes a Http call to another external REST endpoint using WebClient.

I want to know what is the best way to test such a service or controller or endpoint? Wiremock server?
The external endpoint may be offline when the tests are being executed, so should I stub the response?

Please share examples.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I usually use MockServer to mock any external/internal API calls.  check https://www.mock-server.com/ for ref.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR I usually use MockServer to mock any external/internal API calls. check https://www.mock-server.com/ for ref.

---

For Integration tests, I use a combination of rest assured and Mock Server:

1- Add mock-server to your project, I use those:

```
       <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
                <version>${mockserver.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockserver-client-java</artifactId>
                <version>${mockserver.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

2- Setup your mock server:

- set up port that the mock server will be running on:

```
        public class MockInternalServiceServer {
            private final MockServerClient mockServer;
            public static final int PORT = 9600;
    
            public MockInternalServiceServer() {
                this.mockServer = ClientAndServer.startClientAndServer(PORT);
            }
    //shutdown is used in @AfterAll method in your test class
            public void shutdown() {
                mockServer.stop();
            }
    //reset is used in @AfterEach method in your test class
            public void reset() {
                mockServer.reset();
            }
```

- Set up expectations for your test:

```
            public void expectSuccessfulRequest() {
                mockServer.when(expectedRequest())
                        .respond(expectedResponse());
            }
        
            private HttpRequest expectedRequest() {
                return HttpRequest.request() 
             //Add any needed headers here, note that the outgoing request must be identical to the expectation otherwise it will be missed
                        .withMethod("GET")
                        .withPath("/path");
            }
        
            private HttpResponse expectedResponse() {
                return HttpResponse.response()
                        .withStatusCode(200)
                        .withBody(yourResponseBody);
            }
```

- Override the external/internal server URL in application-test.properties, given that you have the external/internal server url in application.properties and not hardcoded:

```
        internal.service.name.baseurl=http://localhost:9600
```

2- In your test class, activate the expectation prior to -in my case- rest assured call:

```
    // Instantiate MockInternalServiceServer in @BeforeAll method, then in your test:
    
        mockInternalServiceServer.expectSuccessfulRequest();
        given().when().get("yourControllerPath").then()...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. One question, I have a Component which implements InitializingBean which fetches data from an external source using REST API. Now the mock server wont be ready by the time the bean is created. How do I ensure that the stubbing is done before the bean is created?

Comment: @Spartacus not sure I can help you with that. If you must keep initializingBean implementation, maybe Mockito is the way to go.